# Slack receiving messages using Python flask and displaying them in a HTML chatbot UI

Tags: python, flask, webhooks, slack, slack-api

I am starting out with implementing a HTML chatbot that can be used by users to send and receive messages to and fro a Slack channel using Python Flask framework. I have been following the tutorial at [https://realpython.com/blog/python/getting-started-with-the-slack-api-using-python-and-flask/](https://realpython.com/blog/python/getting-started-with-the-slack-api-using-python-and-flask/#.V0RhirTC3YY.reddit)

I have a view created which is a simple chatbot ui, but I am stuck with Slack outgoing webhooks. I have reached till

```
@app.route('/slack', methods=['POST'])
def inbound():
    if request.form.get('token') == SLACK_WEBHOOK_SECRET:
        channel = request.form.get('channel_name')
        username = request.form.get('user_name')
        text = request.form.get('text')
        inbound_message = username + " in " + channel + " says: " + text
        print(inbound_message)
    return Response(), 200
```

I have been successful in receiving the message and printing it out to the console whenever there is any message posted in my slack channel. But how do I now pass on this string response over to my view?

I assume this has to be through websockets but could not find any relevant example on google (and am a complete newbie with python and websockets).

Kindly assist me with some help on this or direct me to a proper tutorial on receiving slack messages for a html client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just render the message to your view using `render_template`.

```
from flask import render_template
def inbound():
    if request.form.get('token') == SLACK_WEBHOOK_SECRET:
        channel = request.form.get('channel_name')
        username = request.form.get('user_name')
        text = request.form.get('text')
        inbound_message = username + " in " + channel + " says: " + text
        return render_template('index.html', message=inbound_message)
```

Now, you can retrieve and show the message in your view.

```
                  <p>{{ message }}</p>
```

Alternatively, you can store the message in a `session`, in which case you can access it from the route that renders your view.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, `render_template` wont work as it will cause a refresh of the bot UI. Also, even if I use ajax for displaying this template, there is no way the code can find out when to call this as we wont know when a message has been received from slack. Same goes for sessions too.

Comment: You can use long polling for instance, checking at interval to see if there is a message or not. Also, the route that renders your view can check the session to see if there is a message in it. I am assuming people get to see your view only when they navigate to this route.

Comment: I say long polling, in the case of ajax which you mentioned.

Comment: Aren't websockets a better and modern way of doing this? I found [flask-socketio](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io) for this and trying it out myself. Though a proper example/tutorial for achieving this would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah sure, it is. [Miguel Grinberg has a good beginner tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent) on that.